# HTML5 Canvas circles on click

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been playing around with the HTML5 canvas lately and one of the things I've wanted to do is create a simple page with a canvas that'll draw a circle wherever you click. I have some code that looks like it should work, and I've been attempting to debug with some console output, but I've been unable to see any errors at the moment.

I'm using Codepen though, so I'm unsure how fully featured that console is, and I unfortunately can't use the dev console on my laptop at the moment (locked down school Chromebook).

Could someone take a look? I'll put the code in here and drop a link to the pen as well. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="drawCircle(event)"></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
  position: relative;
  background: #f1c40f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function drawCircle(e) {
  var pos = getCursorPosition(c, e);
  var clickX = pos.x;
  var clickY = pos.y;

  ctx.fillStyle = "#2980b9";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(clickX, clickY, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();

  console.log(clickX, clickY);
  console.log("drawcircle");
}

function getCursorPosition(canvas, e) {
  // Gets click position
  rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  console.log('getcursorpos');

  return {
    x: e.clientX - rect.left, 
    y: e.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/wolverine1621/pen/gWvjgx

Any help is appreciated. It's probably something pretty simple but this is really my first time working with canvas, so any input is helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) you are not setting a width and height for your canvas, so there is going to be distortion and the x/y values are going to be weird. Solution: set the width and height of the canvas to the window height and width

2) Your method for determining clickX and clickY is overly complicated. Solution: use event.clientX and event.clientY

After getting your context, set the width and height:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Note: I would also encourage you to remove the margin on the body in CSS

```
 body { margin: 0 }
```

Now you can get rid of getCursorPosition (because it is giving you wrong values)

```
var clickX = e.clientX
var clickY = e.clientY
```

Comment: Works well now, thanks! Would the method I had used to determine coordinates before be something to save since I believe it was based on having a canvas that doesn't span the entirety of the window?

Comment: I would encourage you to use the offset position of the canvas in addition to the click position to determine the position.  Try to avoid the bounding rect, as that doesn't reflect the resolution of the canvas (for example, you can style a canvas to be 600px but if the width is set to 300, each pixel will be two pixels and bounding rect would give you 600 not 300 as it should)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is occurring because, you set the canvas's `width` and `height` using *css*.

You should rather set it using javascript, like so ...

```
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
```

and to make the canvas flexible, so that it maintains it's size, use ...

```
window.onresize = function() {
  c.width = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Here is the **[working codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmQqdp?editors=0100)**